# Passing pointers from unmanaged code with out modifier

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a (C/C++) DLL which I am calling by DLLImport to a C# project.
This DLL has this method:

```
int __stdcall Connect(OUT int *p_sessionID, IN BYTE mode, IN BYTE comport, IN char *servername, IN DWORD serverport);
```

I tried several ways to "translate" it to C# but one that I find is closer is:

```
[DllImport("UnmanagedDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "Connect", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern unsafe int CS1_Connect(out IntPtr p_sessionID, byte mode, byte comport, string servername, int serverport);
```

I am trying to invoke like this:

```
IntPtr connection;
var i = Connect(out connection, 1, 0, "192.0.0.1", 1982);
```

But I always get the following error:

Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'DllImportTest!DllImportTest.Program::Connect' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

I know I can reach the DLL because I have another method that worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: First argument should be `out int`.  But that does not explain the MDA warning, you'll have to assume that the documentation of the function is outdated.  There is no other way to check, all decoration has been removed.  You must contact the library author for support.

Comment: It would explain the MDA if the target was 64 bit

Comment: Not really, IntPtr grows as well and first 4 args are passed through registers instead of the stack.

Comment: OK, forgot about the registers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first parameter is translated incorrectly.

```
OUT int *p_sessionID
```

Here `OUT` is a macro that indicates semantics to the reader. The macro expands it to nothing. And so after pre-processing you have:

```
int *p_sessionID
```

That translates as

```
out int sessionID
```

in your C#.

You don't need to declare the function as unsafe, remove that. And the final parameter is unsigned. You might want to switch to `uint`.

The correct translation would therefore be:

```
[DllImport("UnmanagedDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "Connect", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int CS1_Connect(
    out int sessionID, 
    byte mode, 
    byte comport, 
    string servername, 
    uint serverport
);
```

If you still receive the stack imbalanced message then you would know that the unmanaged function does not have the signature that you have quoted in the question.

Comment: I have tried it already. But I got the same error. And if I don't use unsafe I cant compile the code.
It was uint in the last parameter. I miss spell when I was typing here.

Comment: This isn't a game of trial and error. That's not the way to go. If the function in my answer leads to the stack imbalance warning then you know that the C function declaration you have does not match the actual function.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help!